# How can we motivate Java & Swing to display all Glyphs / Characters from e.g. Comic Sans MS?

Tags: java, swing, utf-8, fonts

In each Windows application, it's easy to use and display any character from any font.

**For example: display "አማርኛ" in Notepad and use Comic Sans MS:**

1. Open Notepad
2. Change Font: Format » Font » Comic Sans MS
3. Paste the text: አማርኛ

Displaying 'unusual' characters perfectly works - even in this kind of web formula **!**

**In Java and Swing, it's a nightmare, this does just display: ▯▯▯▯**

Sidenotes:

- I use IntelliJ
- The source code file uses utf8 and perfectly display the test string 'አማርኛ'

Code example:

```
Font ComicPln32 = new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.PLAIN, 32);
Font ComicBld32 = new Font(ComicPln32.getName(), Font.BOLD, ComicPln32.getSize());

Border lineBorder = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new Color(222, 49, 99), 2, true);
Border titleBorder = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(lineBorder, "አማርኛ",
                     TitledBorder.LEFT, TitledBorder.TOP, BoldFont, Color.BLUE);
setBorder(titleBorder);
```

Is there no easy way to motivate Java to do its work?

Comment: How is `BoldFont` initialized in the code sample you gave?

Comment: that font cannot display that characters -> `"አማርኛ".codePoints().mapToObj(ComicBld32::canDisplay).toList()` (strange: if I copy that text into Word and change the font to Comic Sana MS, it is changed to Ebrima, not matter what I try) - at least on my system ,that font does not have Glyph for that code points: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfB7C.png (using "Ebrima" works here)

Comment: Notepad is most likely lying to you.  Comic Sans does not contain that character.  Notepad is falling back on other fonts in order to display it.

Answer (score 1):

The ability of a `Font` loaded in Java to display characters depends upon the font itself. There are a lot of tricks used in other software (especially browsers) to 'fill in' a font not supporting particular glyphs, with another font that does.

**But to this specific problem.**

[Spoiler alert: *Comic Sans* does not support those characters.]

[image]

The characters 'abc' are supported by most (including *Comic Sans*), but not all fonts on this system.

[image]

The characters 'አማርኛ' are supported by only one font on this system.

### `TestFonts`

This is the code that produced the above output on this system, using `Font.canDisplayUpTo(..)`. YMMV.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class TestFonts {

    JList<String> fontFamilyList;
    private JPanel gui;
    private String[] allFonts;

    TestFonts() {
        allFonts = GraphicsEnvironment.
                getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAvailableFontFamilyNames();
    }

    private void updateList(String characters) {
        String s = characters;
        ListSelectionModel listSelectionModel = fontFamilyList.getSelectionModel();
        listSelectionModel.clearSelection();
        ListModel listModel = fontFamilyList.getModel();
        for (int ii = 0; ii < listModel.getSize(); ii++) {
            String fontFamily = listModel.getElementAt(ii).toString();
            Font font = new Font(fontFamily, Font.PLAIN, 10);
            if (font.canDisplayUpTo(s) < 0) {
                listSelectionModel.addSelectionInterval(ii, ii);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Runnable r = () -> {
            final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test Fonts");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            TestFonts tf = new TestFonts();

            frame.setContentPane(tf.getGUI());

            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
            frame.setMinimumSize(frame.getSize());

            frame.setVisible(true);
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }

    public JPanel getGUI() {
        if (gui != null) return gui;
        gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
        gui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4)));
        //DefaultListModel allFontModel = new DefaultListModel(allFonts);
        fontFamilyList = new JList(allFonts);
        fontFamilyList.setLayoutOrientation(JList.HORIZONTAL_WRAP);
        fontFamilyList.setVisibleRowCount(40);
        gui.add(new JScrollPane(fontFamilyList), BorderLayout.LINE_START);

        final JTextField inputField = new JTextField(20);
        gui.add(inputField, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        DocumentListener documentListener = new DocumentListener() {
            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                updateList(inputField.getText());
            }

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                updateList(inputField.getText());
            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                updateList(inputField.getText());
            }
        };
        inputField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(documentListener);
        return gui;
    }
}
```